# How can I configure oozie job.properties to skip job at a particular time?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I have created a job and I use oozie to run it every 60 minutes. However, I want to skip the execution of the job at a particular hour. Lets say, my job runs from 10am to 7pm. I want to skip the job execution at 2pm and 4pm. How can I configure these values?
Here is a snippet of my job.properties file

```
nameNode=hdfs://localhost:8020
jobTracker=localhost:8032
jobName=MyJob
userName=${user.name}

oozie.coord.application.path=${nameNode}/user/${userName}/oozie/${jobName}
appPath=${oozie.coord.application.path}

oozie.libpath=/lib
oozie.use.system.libpath=true

timezone=UTC
start=2015-09-01T01:00Z
end=2015-09-04T02:00Z
```

Here is a snippet of my coordinator.xml file

```
<coordinator-app name="${jobName}" frequency="${jobFrequency}"
                 start="${start}" end="${end}" timezone="${timezone}" xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.4">
    <controls>
        <timeout>${timeout}</timeout>
        <concurrency>1</concurrency>
        <throttle>1</throttle>
    </controls>
</coordinator-app>
```

This runs my job every hour from 1st to 4th of the month. How do I skip the job execution at a particular hour? Can I make it configurable in some way?
I used this page for reference.
http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/scheduling-and-coordinating-oozie-workflows-in-had.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the [`Decision Control Node`](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.1.4_Decision_Control_Node) to skip some executions. Decision can be made based on the result of [`coord:nominalTime()`](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.1.3-incubating/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html#a6.7.3._coord:nominalTime_EL_Function):

Coordinator action in coordinator.xml:

```
<action>
    <workflow>
        ...
        <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>nominalHour</name>
                <value>${coord:formatTime(coord:nominalTime(), 'HH')}</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
    </workflow>
</action>
```

Decision control node in workflow.xml:

```
...
<decision name="need-run">
    <switch>
        <case to="skip-run">${nominalHour eq '14'}</case>
        <case to="skip-run">${nominalHour eq '16'}</case>
        <default to="run-my-job"/>
    </switch>
</decision> 
...
```

Comment: @nikoo28 I can offer only the official documentation: workflow https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.1.3-incubating/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html , coordinator https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.1.3-incubating/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html .